# How do I find Green Function for this BVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I saw this question:

Find the Green function for the problem:

$$y''(x)+y(x) = h(x)$$
$$y(0)=y(\pi), y'(0)=y'(\pi)$$

My attempt:

First I should consider the homogeneous case, in that case:

$y''=0 \Longrightarrow y=c_1x+c_2$

$y(0)=y(\pi) \Longrightarrow c_2 = c_1\pi+c_2 \Longrightarrow c_1=0$

So for the first boundary condition I have: $y_1=c_2$ $??$

$y'(0)=y'(\pi) \Longrightarrow c_1=c_1$

It seems like from the second boundary condition I do not get any information about $y_2$ which would help me to calculate the Wronskian and so on. Also I am not sure $y_1$.

Could you please help me?

Comment: For the homogeneous case you get the equation $y'' + y = 0$ and therefore the general solution is $y(x) = A\cos(x) + B\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\Th{\Theta}$We have
$$G(x,x') = [x<x']y_-(x) + [x'<x]y_+(x),$$
where 
$$y_\pm = a_\pm \cos x + b_\pm \sin x$$
and where 
$$[P] = 
\begin{cases}
1, & P\textrm{ true} \\
0, & \textrm{else}
\end{cases}$$
is the Iverson bracket. 
(As @mcd indicates in the comments, the solutions to $y''+y=0$ will be linear combinations of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.) 
The jump and boundary conditions must be satisfied. 
(See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/262854/26872) to a similar problem to understand the first two conditions below.) 
Thus, 
\begin{align*}
y'_-(x') - y'_+(x') &= 1 \\
y_-(x') &= y_+(x') \\
y_-(0) &= y_+(\pi) \\
y'_-(0) &= y'_+(\pi). 
\end{align*}
This system can be solved straightforwardly with the result
$$G(x,x') = ([x'<x]-1/2)\sin(x-x').$$